# Changing the format of the UI date picker

Tags: jquery, user-interface

I am using the UI datepicker and I have already limited the date range possible, bt now, I also want to change the format becuase my mysql database is not storing the dates as the format is not the ISO `format(yyyy-mm-dd)`, it is more `like(dd-mm-yy)`, here is my code please!
:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
        $("#datepicker").datepicker({minDate: +7, maxDate: '+4M +10D'});
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Check - http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Datepicker/$.datepicker.formatDate

Easy as replace dd/mm/yy with format of choice :)

```
.datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy' });
```

Answer (score 1):

Please have a look the [site](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#date-formats):

```
$('#datepicker').datepicker('option', {dateFormat: 'yyyy-mm-dd'});
```

Answer (score 0):

thank you guys, but what worked for min the end was changing the format in the ui datepicker.js script, it was that simple. thank you for anwering though

Answer (score 0):

Well in do in the version for MooTools editing the .js script:

```
  // MooTools.lang
  this.setOptions({
   days: MooTools.lang.get('Date', 'days'),
   months: MooTools.lang.get('Date', 'months'),
   //format: MooTools.lang.get('Date', 'shortDate'),
   format: '%d-%m-%Y',
   selectTimeTitle : MooTools.lang.get('DatePicker', 'select_a_time'),
   timeConfirmButton : MooTools.lang.get('DatePicker', 'time_confirm_button')
  });
```